# CancellationToken not causing OperationCanceledException to be thrown

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to restart a `Task` in case it is already running using a `CancellationToken`. Here is my code:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
CancellationToken cancellationToken;

private void OnButtonCLick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();

    cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                Console.WriteLine("test");
                // ... calculation lasting few milliseconds ...
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex) { }
    }, cancellationToken);
}
```

For some reason the `OperationCanceledException` does not get thrown when calling `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` gets called. I compared it to other examples but don't see a reason why this does not work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your task is reading the `cancellationToken` field, which will point to the new (not yet cancelled) token. Instead, you must make sure to keep using the one that was originally given to your task:

```
var token = cancellationToken;

Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            Console.WriteLine("test");
            // ... calculation lasting few milliseconds ...
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex) { }
}, token);
```